# Having some trouble centering the logo inside the div that will hold my menu

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="main-menu">
    <a id="main-menu-logo" href="index.html">
        <span style="color:white;">MY NAME</span>
    </a>
    <div id="main-menu-items">
        ......
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#main-menu{
    margin-left: 1px;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;   
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width: 120px;
}

#main-menu-items{
    display: none;
}

#main-menu-logo {   
    line-height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

How can I get the main-menu-logo to be centered inside the main-menu?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can centre using display:table and margin.

```
#main-menu-logo {   
    line-height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

More info here: [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful link and answer.  I have one more question in regards to your solution if you don't mind.  I have a small javascript that changes the dimensions of the main-menu upon clicking it.  However, I am trying to add also a float:right to main-menu-logo.  It does not seem to work - can you please tell me what is wrong?  $("#main-menu-logo").animate({"float":"right"},250)

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.  You need to do something like:        $('#main-menu-logo').animate({
            'float': 'right',
            'width' : 250
        },  "slow"); and of course fire it using the click() method.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: No problems - glad i could help :)